# Is there any limit for form fields to use jquery serialize() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey anybody have an idea on maximum number of form feilds to use jquery `serialize()` function because my from dynamically add fields up to 1000 fields and more. But it is only serializing first 200(apx) field ...

please help me. is there any solution for this ..??

Comment: Why do you have 1000+ fields to begin with? That doesn't sound very user friendly.

Comment: its from my admin area's data entry...

Comment: any idea to solve this..??

Comment: if not Post-data ,try localstorage ?

Comment: Presumably you're not actually changing 1000+ fields in each request, can you change your script to only send the fields which have been updated?

Comment: @eric_zyh: How does this help if the data is needed on the server?

Comment: @Pudge601 you are on my track..that is the only solution in front of me...but hopping for the better here..

Comment: There are different ways of accomplishing this, you may want to simply split the fields into separate forms so that only the relevant fields are sent, or you could look into the concept of having "dirty" fields, though this may take a big redesign of your script

Answer (score 1):

The body of your request (Post-Data, GET-Query) is limited in length. There is no common standard, but e.g. Suoshin tends to limit it so something like 2 or 4 kb. So 200 might just be the limit your Server recieves, no matter what the browser sends.

The reason is DDoS-Protection: As The Post-data is converted into an array, a huge request, sent some thousand times, could fill servers memory and bring the server down.

Comment: Good point, but not more than a guess since you don't know what server the OP uses (and how it is configured). You haven't provided a solution for the problem though.

Comment: i hope i can change that limit from the server(php), but on serialize()..? have experienced these kind of prob..mate??